# Will Vivado HLS arbitrary precision types support in XSDK?

Tags: xilinx-edk, vivado-hls

I designed a function in HLS IPcore which process arrays of arbitrary precision types.I connected that core to the MICROBLAZE processor and generated Bitstream.

I wrote C Codes in SDK to initialize HW IP core and to compile the codes. In TERA TERMINAl, the arbitrary precision variables does not seem to be working.
So, whether VIVADO HLS arbitrary precision types support in XSDK ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some example code, the expected output, and what the end result is?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understood what you meant, but the ap_int library with template seems to be what you will need.